# App works fine when installed via Android studio but Play store puts it on unsupported device list

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an app that has been on the play store for over a year now. I updated it to be compatible with Android 10, removed android.support libraries and updated to AndroidX. When I tried to deploy it on the Play Store it is dropping support on ALL devices saying that the devices do not have the following:

- android.bluetooth
- android.hardware.usb
- android.location
- android.hardware.location
- android.hardware.microphone
- android.hardware.bluetooth

Below is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.location" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb" android:required="true"/>
```

My minSdkVersion is 23 and targetSdkVersion is 29.

Answer (score 1):

remove last 3 lines of "required" and then try.
You must code different for above features at android 10 and below 10.
There are some access related restrictions from android 10.